# electronのmain processでbabelなどを使わずにES6のarrow functionを使う

Tags: javascript, electron

electronでapplicationを作っているのですがES6のarrow functionを使いたいと考えています。babelなどのライブラリを使えばできますが、
そのようなものを使わずにelectronだけでarrow functionを使えるようにする方法はないのでしょうか?

`iojs --harmony_arrow_functions`とするとarrow functionが有効にされた状態でio.jsが起動します。
このiojsの機能を使って、electronでarrow functionを使いたいのですが、何か方法はありますか?

### 追記:

main.jsのコード

```
var app = require("app");
require("crash-reporter").start();
var BrowserWindow = require("browser-window");

//Keep a reference of window Object, if don't, window will be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is GCed(Gabage Collection)

var mainWindow = null;

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform != "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
})

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    mainWindow.loadUrl("file://" + __dirname + "/index.html");
    //mainWindow.openDevTools();
    mainWindow.on("closed", function () {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v8`モジュールを使ってください。

```
var v8 = require('v8');
v8.setFlagsFromString('--harmony_arrow_functions');
```

https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1328#issuecomment-89810268

Comment: リンク先の方法ではv8のflagをsetした後にrequireでファイルを読み込む方法でしたが、この方法を使った場合、main processが2つのファイルに分かれてしまいます。 2つのファイルに分けなくてもよい方法はありますか?

Comment: 2つのファイルに分割するデメリットはあまりないと思うのですが、1つのファイルで実現するにはelectron自体に手を加えないと無理じゃないでしょうか。現在electronが採用しているChromeのバージョンが44で、arrow functionが45からなので対応するを待つという方法もありますが。